# Get Italian names from Wikipedia Api

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

We are trying to fetch **italian** data from wikipedia's api. We have multiple names and need to get the first 10 results.

e.g. we want to collect the data from the "Persone" section of this result: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_(nome)

Right now the I'm trying this approach:

```
$kw = $name."_(nome)";
$url = "http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=".$kw."&prop=revisions&rvprop=content";
```

Other questions did not help much, i'm getting no output.

Comment: are you using `file_get_contents()`??? Just setting a variable to a URL does not get that URL's contents.

Comment: What do you mean, no output? Are you getting an error? Are you aware that [you have to set the `User-Agent` header](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#Identifying_your_client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [php dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/),
[Docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

By simple lookup in their dom here is the code for the first name:

```
require('dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$name = 'Francesco';
$kw = $name . '_(nome)';
$html = file_get_html('http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . $kw);

$span = $html->getElementById('Persone');
$h2 = $span->parent();


$ul = $h2->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling();

$lis = $ul->find('li');

foreach($lis as $li){
    echo($li->plaintext . '<br />');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good advice. The problem with "persone" is that is used only some time..